# как установить (загрузить, не знаю как правильно) DL4J в Intellij?

Tags: java

На сайте, насколько я понял, предлагают скачать сразу примеры и их разбирать.

Comment: не знал что ответы надо отмечать. нет, многие ответы мне помогли. принципа тут никакого нет

Comment: Надо отмечать, но только если помогло. Это как минимум является неким маяком для остальных посетителей, столкнувшихся со схожей ситуацией, что данный ответ стоит рассмотреть для решения их проблемы и не проверяя остальные, порой 3-4-5-6 ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаём maven проект в pom.xml, указываем следующие зависимости

```
deeplearning4j-core

nd4j-native-platform

datavec-api
```

Пример зависимости:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

На их сайте в разделе Getting Started всё написано.